# Why is changing the shutter speed while taking video an option on my DSLR and what is the point in doing it?

Tags: canon, shutter-speed, video

I own a `Canon EOS 2000D` and I noticed that when I shoot video I have the option to change the shutter speed. And I have three questions about it:

Why is that an option?
What does changing it do?
Why would I change it?

Comment: If it was not for video, but for taking photos, would you know what changing the shutter speed would do?

Comment: If no, perhaps this previous question will be of use: https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/5586/9161 .  
If you do know what the shutter speed does in photos, this question might be helpful: https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/11131/9161

Comment: check here (second answer): https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/8283/shutter-speed-when-recording-with-dslr

Comment: This question belongs on [video.se]. However, I'm hesitant to migrate it because it likely a dupe of their question, [Shutter speed when recording with DSLR](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/8283/shutter-speed-when-recording-with-dslr). Instead, I have closed it as a dupe of the similar question here (asked in the early days of Photo-SE, before video-related questions were decided to be off-topic), [What shutter speed to use when shooting video?](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/11131)

Comment: Displaying links like this isn't all that hard and only takes a few extra clicks:  [How do I use the different shutter speeds my camera offers?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/5586/15871) and [What shutter speed to use when shooting video?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/11131/15871) and [this answer](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/8342/4089) to [Shutter speed when recording with DSLR](https://video.stackexchange.com/q/8283/4089)

Comment: Displaying links with titles isn't difficult, but if you don't know the syntax, you can't figure it out from comments, because you can't see the raw input.  `[question title](https://actual.url)` shows in comments as [question title](https://actual.url) <- doesn't go anywhere, of course.